# xcode crashed when merging a branch and deleted the last month of work

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

I had made a few new views in a new branch off of the master branch and had finally finished making those and was ready to merge back to to master branch but xcode crashed right in the middle of the merge and now source control says my last commit was 14 days ago and has reverted to that version even though i have been committing it every day.  Does anyone know how to get the files back and get my source control to remember the most recent commits. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try "git reflog" to see if you see any of the commits? If you see the the commits, you can use "git reset --hard HEAD^" to go back to that commit. "HEAD^" in this case is the commit hash you will see with "git reflog".

Comment: Great!, I'll go ahead and move that to "Answer"

Answer (score 1):

Try "git reflog" to see if you see all your previous commits.

Use "git reset --hard HEAD^" to go back to that commit. "HEAD^" in this case is the commit hash you will see with "git reflog".